# Blackberry Application signing problem

Tags: blackberry

hi i m new to blackberry.
 i m developing an app which requires code signing. so i  fill the app form and get 3 csi files. as i click on csi files they ask for password and any other things.
and i provide all the things. and get successfully registerd with rim.
but i m working in eclipse. so as click on Project->BlackBerry->Sign with signature tool. as i click on this there is an error which said  unable to launch the signature tool as signing keys can not be found.
 and as i click ok it takes me again to registration process.

why this is happening as i already registered with rim.i am not getting this situation 
please help me.

and as try to register it again it says that your registration attempts are no more.

Comment: Email RIM's support: devsupport@rim.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the keys.  Usually there are instructions in the email containing the keys from RIM, but here an online article that explains to how install them, as well: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/20779/Obtain_and_install_signing_keys_1264848_11.jsp

Comment: sir  t try this.but as i try to import existing keys.and as i navigate up to that folder in which i have put keys. it shows nothing. even it is not opening that folder. this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if you've changed PCs or Reinstalled OS. A set of keys AFAIK are only valid for one single PC. That said, RIM dev support can move those keys to the new PC for you if you ask them.

Comment: My problem get solved. Thanks to all. actually i forget to add csi files in C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.7.0\bin folder. as i add these 3 csi files in this folder problem get solved.